# Remove lines from txt script for python plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, graph

I have a very simple working python file that creates graphs from txtfiles, using the following code;

```
filename = "curve_htc6000_2.txt"
setTemp = 200

df = pd.read_csv(filename, delim_whitespace=True)
Time1 = df.iloc[:,0]
Power1 = df.iloc[:,1]
Time2 = df.iloc[:,2]
Power2 = df.iloc[:,3]

fig1 = plt.gcf()
plt.axhline(y = 225, color = '0.5', linestyle = '--') 
plt.plot(Time1, Power1, 'co--', linewidth=2, markersize=3, label="MS_HTC6000")
plt.plot(Time2, Power2, 'b*--', linewidth=2, markersize=3, label="FS_HTC6000")

plottitle = 'Power usage'
plt.title(plottitle)
plt.xlabel('Cycles [s]')
plt.ylabel('Power [W]')
plt.figtext(.7, .8, "T = 200C")
```

My input files look like the following.
In reality, it contains way more rows, but I only included few:

```
2190.89224179698    41.447689056396484      2190.89224179698    25.676259994506836  
2190.89225179698    41.447689056396484      2190.89225179698    25.676259994506836  
2190.8923695739136  41.447689056396484      2190.8923695739136  25.676259994506836  
2190.893174567645   41.44767761230469       2190.893174567645   25.676258087158203
```

This is after I remove some lines with string text, because the original looks like this:

```
"Power Curve Thermocouple TC_MS"            "Power Curve Thermocouple TC_FS"    
"AUTime"    "AUPercent"     "AUTime"    "AUPercent" 
"s" "%"     "s" "%" 
2190.89224179698    41.447689056396484      2190.89224179698    25.676259994506836  
2190.89225179698    41.447689056396484      2190.89225179698    25.676259994506836  
2190.8923695739136  41.447689056396484      2190.8923695739136  25.676259994506836  
2190.893174567645   41.44767761230469       2190.893174567645   25.676258087158203
```

Now, I manually have to remove the first lines everytime I open a new file. I would love to learn how I edit my code to use the data (starts at fourth row) for my plots and additionally keep the text to use for e.g. the legend or title of my plot

Comment: How many values are at each row? is it exactly equal to the number of columns?

Answer (score 4):

Since you are using `read_csv()` function to read data from the file, you can pass a parameter named `skiprows` that defines the number of rows to skip. The following line is from `read_csv()` documentation :

> Line numbers to skip (0-indexed) or number of lines to skip (int) at
> the start of the file.

```
filename = "curve_htc6000_2.txt"
setTemp = 200

df = pd.read_csv(filename, delim_whitespace=True,skiprows=4)
```

If it uses one row of data as column name, you can tell it not to use that rows as header by setting `header=None` :

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, delim_whitespace=True,skiprows=4,header=None)
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy to understand solution would be:

```
with open('curve_htc6000_2.txt','r') as file: #this opens the file. 'r' means read only.
    lines = file.readlines()# this reads the entire file

with open("curve_htc6000_2_stripped.txt",'w') as newfile: # same as before, 'w' means we make a new file, note I have given it a different name.
    for line in lines: # loop over the lines we have read in the original file.
        if not '"' in line: # check for a unique character that only exists in lines you want to remove, if it does not exist, keep line:
            newfile.write(line)
```

Your full code would look like:

```
with open('curve_htc6000_2.txt','r') as file: #this opens the file. 'r' means read only.
    lines = file.readlines()# this reads the entire file

with open("curve_htc6000_2_stripped.txt",'w') as newfile: # same as before, 'w' means we make a new file, note I have given it a different name.
    for line in lines: # loop over the lines we have read in the original file.
        if not '"' in line: # check for a unique character that only exists in lines you want to remove, if it does not exist, keep line:
            newfile.write(line)

filename = "curve_htc6000_2_stripped.txt"
setTemp = 200


df = pd.read_csv(filename, delim_whitespace=True)
Time1 = df.iloc[:,0]
Power1 = df.iloc[:,1]
Time2 = df.iloc[:,2]
Power2 = df.iloc[:,3]

fig1 = plt.gcf()
plt.axhline(y = 225, color = '0.5', linestyle = '--') 
plt.plot(Time1, Power1, 'co--', linewidth=2, markersize=3, label="MS_HTC6000")
plt.plot(Time2, Power2, 'b*--', linewidth=2, markersize=3, label="FS_HTC6000")

plottitle = 'Power usage'
plt.title(plottitle)
plt.xlabel('Cycles [s]')
plt.ylabel('Power [W]')
plt.figtext(.7, .8, "T = 200C")
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick and elaborate answer. I tried to use your code, however it results in the error: No columns to parse from file.  Also, the stripped file appears to be completely empty in my folder.

Comment: My guess is the error is a result of my code snippet not working properly. I think it had to do with the way I had coded the if statement. I made an edit, try the code above.